# My exe run only dll's in exe file together. i need run exe from file how can i?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, deployment, dll

i created imported DLL in  references. My plugin need these DLL but they are in common or plugin file if i click reference add dll they import form plugins file . they must be only in only plugins or common not two place. Look picture below: [image]

if i click add refrence ClearCanvas's DLL and PluginTest Dll must be only plugins file !!!
[image]

Comment: Not sure if I understood you correctly but you don't want the same reference to be in both projects? In that case, you could remove the reference by right-clicking and Remove?

Comment: i added dll into references they must run from only one file this file plugins but where pluginTest dll need others . right clicked change copy local false but not useful :(

Comment: Hard to decode.  You'll probably want to use ILMerge.  Link: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=22914587-b4ad-4eae-87cf-b14ae6a939b0&displaylang=en

Comment: I read this 4 times now. I still cannot grasp what problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Setup project which will install the files into one location...that is the end goal isn't it, on a user system?

Answer (score 0):

You do not want your auxiliary dlls copied over when your app is deployed - is this what you want? You can place them in the GAC, you will have to sign them though